# How to manage layers and colums in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I start from [this trellis chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-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-g+UQxMWiTJKkfoZIk2S5BEopQCMxygEc7RoKugifEoOAEkuZDTgADMqHaWFqIBbjuGgwRm8HPIhubIah6H3ho2G4b6zikL4xEaG4bDDGYCR9GwAy0eMDFKNAzHjmxbAcSM3EgLx1j8UJIk3mwcLOFOqAANqbiBYGdnYhG3qp6AHkeaQ6f4D5qJ87YALpKFM1yBVJ6AJWFGEaFFx66koZhkNmYFBLpbx2DQAF-ExQKgFwiAPsMTBmEgDDzIJ7YeSAsRwtp4nWfVIBAeBsi2Pe43Zr8YkgNkE2ldN3XKkAA), in which I have 3 columns.

[image]

I must add a rule, than I need to use a layer. I have edit my config and now I [have this one](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBWOgCtY3AHaQANOChL0qZNih4ATsjETYAfXboDY5AE81GyABNkCA40J4eKnJAAqRiaMsA4QkF54NnqgEGF4yAAeeHqQAJJK1EawsIxgTNwGWhLI7mCMSmB%20JeiEjOhg6fFKORT1ABR%20qQCUYPXwygBmBsp43GD9Fe79VKWjeOgSZRWdobGQ-WIFKQDEAIwAbAAcAMLHAOyrYQMjAMqMAF66OLuH6rFQ6EpIW76w8wbJN5ra5KZK%20ACyI1gJQM6EBGjCsA4ESivgAMgU0GViKxUGAnNxNgYwDk8L0dHhVONlND4PE8KxiegnB5gvBytQwMZmHQwAA5bTUpStIKwLlKRh49DwMBDDmMEz1AbIVhMOGXKBI9go5AAMRGKUhoOhBlhyQ0AF8gc44ZgcDE1oyxCl8EQSORYQB3BjMNjsVgmiZNPB0fqoUjKJy20jTRhOXYATmYCzqpAwfxKpGM6HYBXQ928jFITkI8DMsfjCdI8VhtXQjWQzUYrVIhGG8FcOQy1eqdYbTdaACUaDduNQJPR4LAKJBLdaBtLkGCwA6roxjE4Ui4lNxUOV895kGYjPklLogXFbIQnlACiyihr1oTcc09ABmC-6ZioqCziBWxxYGveBogRKAxHQWwSj0ABtMCIFXd4oAwAwAGsUkIbhynhJC1hQRhqHwaJIAzQg9F2AAmADcLCRt%20nvahQJotYEiY5jgXXMRN18DkshyMwaxqOozGwxsWnQMxUFQDVmPCK8b0gABHVhPgiOFm3PeCaPCb8FPSTJO1yfJChTEpcnKSpUhk7SEAWG9gEgR5hj0BcxGhKlIEIZkGPIgAGC0tPeaj2Mgex7UCpDIAGTjuP0XthNEgcJKk6zcLk68UmU1Tky8KhUsinUUj8bh5hsMApm4GZzOWKzP1k2yfwcpzuBchZ3KgLynB855-Ii-86oK7hCS8MicBghzoo3FIdGhNR9HklIdz3B8PMK3wZt0C0AF0BveJ8iTY9ioEmrjptcTSjsvDLfCW-dnV2yKbGoRtYoctaoHBVxGEgYKjpI%20A7OI-g0AU%20Z2BsdBWF2Xyfr6sAAuYhGkN%202JEL2lD0PtdKFIMVgog8jYfigIxNxRva6O4bqVzh0LiJO2KSLHCc3xh1aFt8LLQRyjS5p0yIbyUPGxDJyKckeYiRVYG9diR3DZdieWtrnRx8MI5cHNI8iqOtLJCTyrGGvsyBWJ4pQXGvM3G0BKAwqgcpzZeq2foCi0gA): I lost the columns and i have everything on one line.

How not to lose the arrangement in columns?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap up your entire `facet` and `layer` inside an `vconcat` and provided a `columns: 3` outside facet. Refer the below code or [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-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%20QzWZzlQASuRdmwyMIqFAIMQQKqQMQelARagANqgKZQ8poADMjw5cBeoBaNF01g0tlkbAQ2UjLjgBh0yVk6iUmHMOGOIBShLSvjoQJA7aUECPUECIEESHMGTQA5AyC0AGsNDg2NkvzZs0Z5kI%20ISPrO84aKSsTxAYaYFEUBiAdmFRIAYCAIL4h7HgAjgwFx%20D8uZ7pol7HlEMTFokySpH6GSJNkuQRKKPZAqARztGgLQjJ8Sg4ASoFoPMAAMyodpYWogFBggLugiEZihzxobmGFYThR4aARRG%20s4pAXv4x5uGwwxmAkfRsAMTHjKxt7sccnEZGwPF8XAAlCaSIniR2nRws4ODvjOc5yRoaifJpx7Lqu577hRYV2OoyoALpKFM1zBdB6DhWRB5aeg0VrrqShmGQ2byUE8VvHYNA3n8DmPlwiDHsMTBmEgDBie2EmqqAX6-tJeXHloDABGlcLXCAOgLh2wFsMJ0lSZloU3A2TajqJkXaYRzx6aRhlArIo2CB28RHI%20jIMMc8w9clHaxHCBnSdAIyOSAEHoNkthHrIS6-FJIBfXAP1-d1KXKkAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "name": "trellis_barley",
  "description": "Trellis",
  "title": {
    "text": "Ingressi giornalieri in Terapia Intensiva (TI) a confronto con ricoveri totali in TI",
    "color": "#168CC7",
    "fontSize": 18,
    "anchor": "start",
    "font": "Montserrat",
    "subtitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam convallis enim ac fringilla feugiat",
    "subtitleFont": "Montserrat"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ondata/covid19italia/master/elaborazioni/dpc_covid19/terapiaIntensiva/processing/terapiaIntensivaRegSoglia.csv"
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "columns": 3,
      "facet": {
        "field": "denominazione_regione",
        "type": "ordinal",
        "title": ""
      },
      "spec": {
        "layer": [
          {
            "mark": "point",
            "encoding": {
              "x": {
                "field": "ingressi_terapia_intensiva_mm",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "title": "Ingressi giornalieri in TI",
                "scale": {"zero": false, "padding": 10}
              },
              "y": {
                "field": "terapia_intensiva_mm",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "title": "Totale ricoveri in TI",
                "scale": {"zero": false, "padding": 10}
              },
              "tooltip": [
                {"field": "mese", "type": "nominal", "title": "mese"}
              ],
              "color": {
                "field": "mese",
                "type": "nominal",
                "legend": {"title": "Mesi"},
                "scale": {"scheme": "tableau10"}
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "red"},
            "encoding": {
              "y": {"field": "soglia30", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
              "size": {"value": 1}
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works great, but why does the y title disappear?
As usual thank you very much

Comment: Just remove the `title: null` from y-axis encoding. The title will be back.